# Java classpath NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, jar

I am trying to run testjar.jar , that depends on ConnectionException class residing in wsc-22.jar

Both jar is in the same folder.

What's wrong with bellow command..? (It is working well in Eclipse, i just exported into testjar.jar)

Thank you ..

```
lib > java -cp ./wsc-22.jar  -jar testjar.jar 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sforce/ws/ConnectionException
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use -cp (nor -classpath) along with -jar

do `java -cp ./wsc-22.jar;testjar.jar my.package.Main`

substitute the above accordingly

Another option is to add wsc-22.jar in the testjar.jar manifest file.

For instance in testjar.jar:

**MANIFEST.MF**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0  
Main-Class: my.path.to.the.main.Application  
Class-Path: wsc-22.jar
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works after I change from semicolon to colon